# JavaScript: How to access elements using dynamic names

Tags: javascript, optimization, dynamic, element

The project I'm currently working on is quite simple and uses oCanvas to draw a 7-segment digital clock (there are six sets of segments in total representing HH:MM:SS). My code is working correctly but the element names are hard-coded and I would like to optimise my script so that I end up with a function that takes the name of the segment "set" (say, the right-most digit of the seconds column) as well as a TRUE/FALSE value for each of the segments (1 through to 7) and then change the colour of the oCanvas element depending on whether it is supposed to be switched on or not.

My function currently looks like this, and I have just included the code for the right-most digit of the seconds column - in practice there are six conditions in the if() test, and not just the one shown:

```
function display_segments(type,seg_01,seg_02,seg_03,seg_04,seg_05,seg_06,seg_07)
{
    var segment_on = "#FF0000";
    var segment_off = "#333333";
    var seg_val_01, seg_val_02, seg_val_03, seg_val_04, seg_val_05, seg_val_06, seg_val_07;

    (seg_01) ? seg_val_01 = segment_on : seg_val_01 = segment_off;
    (seg_02) ? seg_val_02 = segment_on : seg_val_02 = segment_off;
    (seg_03) ? seg_val_03 = segment_on : seg_val_03 = segment_off;
    (seg_04) ? seg_val_04 = segment_on : seg_val_04 = segment_off;
    (seg_05) ? seg_val_05 = segment_on : seg_val_05 = segment_off;
    (seg_06) ? seg_val_06 = segment_on : seg_val_06 = segment_off;
    (seg_07) ? seg_val_07 = segment_on : seg_val_07 = segment_off;

    // This section needs optimising    
    if (type == 'seconds_right') {
        segment_01_seconds_right.stroke = "5px " + seg_val_01;
        segment_02_seconds_right.stroke = "5px " + seg_val_02;
        segment_03_seconds_right.stroke = "5px " + seg_val_03;
        segment_04_seconds_right.stroke = "5px " + seg_val_04;
        segment_05_seconds_right.stroke = "5px " + seg_val_05;
        segment_06_seconds_right.stroke = "5px " + seg_val_06;
        segment_07_seconds_right.stroke = "5px " + seg_val_07;
    } else {
        // 5 else if() tests at this point
    }

    canvas.redraw(); // oCanvas
}
```

What I would like to do is replace this code with a for() loop that uses whatever the value in the "type" variable currently is in place of the hard-coded element name "segment_XX_seconds_right" but I can't work out how to do this and I don't want to use eval() if possible.

Thanks in advance for any help or advice!

Comment: are you looking for variable variables?

Comment: Everything is wrong including using a ternary with side effects. I would try to fix it but it is bedtime here. What is segment_01_seconds_right anyway? `seg_val_01 = (seg_01)?segment_on : segment_off;`

Comment: Possibly - my problem is knowing how to access the canvas element using the value in the "type" variable. I tried accessing it with ["segment_01_" + type].stroke but that didn't work - I didn't get any errors but nothing happened.

Comment: `for (var n=1;n<8;n++) { window['segment_0'+n+'_seconds_right'].stroke = "5px " + window['seg_val_0'+n];` }

Comment: Ha, that is what I posted and then deleted again since I did not know if the segments where in the window scope

Comment: i don't know if they are or not; it's an assumption. @NoelWhitemore if it's not in window scope then you'll have to alter it accordingly. Basically the principle is to put it as an index of the parent object

Comment: The script is functionality correct so I don't really see what the problem is - I'd be interested to know what you think is wrong with it though. The "segment_01_seconds_right" reference is a line drawn using oCanvas that represents one of the segments - the code in the if() test is applying a stroke of 5px width in either red or dark grey depending on whether the segment is supposed to be on or not.

Comment: though honestly that's a cheap optimization. Ideally you want to restructure how you're doing this. example targeting by a common class instead of individual ids. Or using an array instead of individual vars. etc..

Comment: Accessing the oCanvas element using window[] doesn't seem to work. I understand your point about restructuring the code but I just need to get to grips with this problem first if I can.